# File Upload - Unexpected token illegal

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass the filename of a file uploaded by a user to a label. Using this on wordpress. I am getting error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on line `fileName = e.target.value.split( '\' ).pop();`

Could this be that I need to change the `$` symbols to `jQuery`?

```
'use strict';

;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    $( '.inputfile' ).each( function()
    {
        var $input   = $( this ),
            $label   = $input.next( 'label' ),
            labelVal = $label.html();

        $input.on( 'change', function( e )
        {
            var fileName = '';

            if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
                fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
            else if( e.target.value )
                fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

            if( fileName )
                $label.find( 'span' ).html( fileName );
            else
                $label.html( labelVal );
        });

        // Firefox bug fix
        $input
        .on( 'focus', function(){ $input.addClass( 'has-focus' ); })
        .on( 'blur', function(){ $input.removeClass( 'has-focus' ); });
    });
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the line on your code block features a double back-slash, rather than a single back-slash.

Comment: it's strange because when i write the code is '\\' and chrome shows it as '\' on the console..